# jquery add 1 to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split

Having this

```
class="row45"
```

I would like to make it "row46" using jquery or simple javascript

Tried something like this:

```
var row = $(this).parents('tr').prev();
var rclass = row.attr('class');
var class_number = rclass.match(/(\d+)/g);
```

but that only gave me the number 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did:

```
var row = $(this).parents('tr').prev();
var rclass = row.attr('class');
var class_number = rclass.match(/(\d+)/g);
```

After this simply do:

```
class_number = parseInt(class_number) + 1;
rclass = "row"+class_number;
row.attr("class", rclass);
```

And that row will now have class "row46" and rclass will have string "row46".

Answer (score 2):

Take that string, convert it to a number, and add one

```
var class_number = rclass.match(/(\d+)/g)[0];
var num = parseInt(class_number, 10) + 1;
console.log(num);  //46
```

another way with replace

```
var nextClass = rclass.replace(/(\d+)/g, function(a){ return parseInt(a,10) + 1; });
console.log(nextClass);  //row46
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [String.replace(regexp, function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for this kind of thing.

```
// returns "row46"
"row45".replace(/(\d+)/, function(theString, theNumber) {
    return (+theNumber) + 1;
});
```